# Stop UIScrollView scrolling during touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Is there a way to stop a `UIScrollView` from scrolling ***while a touch is still held down***? Setting the content offset using the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method is excessive and can cause some issues (view moves and resets quickly) with the GPU, so I was hoping for a cleaner solution, if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply turn it out by using its property **scrollEnabled** in viewDidLoad..

```
self.myScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Please note: "during touch"

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [scrollView setScrollingEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [scrollView setScrollingEnabled:NO];
}
```

That will turn it off for a press and you can adjust detecting how far the "Move" was from the original touch to see if you want to reenable scrolling or not

Comment: That will only work when the view is touched. I'm asking about while the view currently being touched.

Comment: ah ok I was thinking the touches began still triggered on a long touch my bad.

Comment: It only triggers when the touches being, are moved or are ended. However the `setScrollingEnabled:NO` will also cause the jittery animation when the view moves before disabling. This doesn't have anything to do with long touches. Thank you for the response!